# Cisco ACL reverse wildcard vs object-group

Tags: cisco, firewall, acl

I have three service group, `WWW, SMTP and FTP`. I wanted to isolate using `wildcard` mask and divide them in logical subnet.

Example: We have 192.168.100.0/24 subnet, In short i want to give 50% IPs to WWW and 25% - SMTP and rest 25% FTP

```
www - 128 host
smtp - 64 host
ftp - 64 host
```

## UPDATE

My ACL will be like this.

```
access-list 101 permit tcp any 192.168.100.0 0.0.0.127 eq www
access-list 101 permit tcp any 192.168.100.128 0.0.0.63 eq smtp
access-list 101 permit tcp any 192.168.100.192 0.0.0.63 eq ftp
```

But i want to use `object-group` and there you can't use wildcard so how do i adjust above mask in object-group with subnetmask?

is following is correct in respect of `wildcard` masking?`

```
object-group network WWW-ACL
   192.168.100.0 255.255.255.128
object-group network SMTP-ACL
   192.168.100.128 255.255.255.192
object-group network FTP-ACL
   192.168.100.191 255.255.255.192
```

Define them in ACL

```
access-list 101 permit tcp any object-group WWW-ACL eq www
access-list 101 permit tcp any object-group SMTP-ACL eq www
access-list 101 permit tcp any object-group FTP-ACL eq www
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A wildcard mask is just the inverse (change the `0` bits to `1`, and vice versa) of a regular mask:

- Wildcard mask `0.0.0.127` is regular mask `255.255.255.128`
- Wildcard mask `0.0.0.63` is regular mask `255.255.255.192`

**Edit:**

What I think you want is object groups like:

```
object-group network WWW-ACL
   192.168.100.0 255.255.255.128
object-group network SMTP-ACL
   192.168.100.128 255.255.255.192
object-group network FTP-ACL
   192.168.100.192 255.255.255.192
```

Comment: In my case third subnet will be `192.168.100.191 255.255.255.0`  can you specify base on my question

Comment: Not from what you have for `access-list 101 permit tcp any 192.168.100.192 0.0.0.255 eq ftp`. The `0.0.0.255` wildcard mask translates to `255.255.255.0`.

Comment: what should i use can you put in your answer, i need specific answer to not myself confused :(

Comment: Also, in your object groups, the last two actually translate to the same range, and the last one does't match what you have in the wildcard masks. You have me confused about what you really want.

Comment: I have /24 subnet and i want to divide them in 3 service,  50% - WWW and 25% SMTP and 25% FTP. base on that i calculate mask i may be wrong there that is why i post question to find out how to do that?

Comment: I have updated my question which i screwed wildcard mask before, it should be `0.0.0.63`

Comment: OK, but your object group address for `ftp` seems to be one less than I think you want it to be, that puts it in the same range as the `smtp`.

Comment: what do you mean less than? Please explain.  if you run subnet mask it will do correctly devid. here it's we are not going to loose network and broadcast subnet so why it will loose a bit?

Comment: The `smtp` range includes the address you are using for `ftp` in the object groups. See what is in my answer.

Comment: Got it `191` should be `192`